# How the class should be without error in MySQL?

Tags: mysql

When I inserted this data to my database's table, I got below error which is not easy for me to solve.

```
INSERT INTO 'student' ('id', 'name', 'roll', 'address') 
VALUES (NULL, 'Rahul', '101', 'Ranchi'), (NULL, 'Rohit', '102', 'Delhi')
```

> 1064 - You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that
>   corresponds to your MariaDB server version for the right syntax to use
>   near ''student' ('id', 'name', 'roll', 'address') VALUES (NULL,
>   'Rahul', '101', 'Ranch' at line 1

Comment: Can you post the Table structure?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [When to use single quotes, double quotes, and backticks in MySQL](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11321491/when-to-use-single-quotes-double-quotes-and-backticks-in-mysql)

Comment: Please post the table structure. Otherwise, we cannot assume the answer to your question. Anyway please refer [MySQL Error 1064](https://www.inmotionhosting.com/support/website/databases/error-1064)

Answer (score 0):

Remove '' from table column names as well as table name and you are good to go. Try this:

```
INSERT INTO student (id, name, roll, address)
VALUES
  (NULL, 'Rahul', '101', 'Ranchi'),(NULL, 'Rohit', '102', 'Delhi');
```

Also, there are various websites such as W3schools to check the sql command syntax, kindly use them for such errors.

Comment: I applied this but it didn't work, BTW thanks for your feedback

Comment: I have provided the correct syntax for your query. In case this does not work, you need to provide your table structure.